# Find min/max values in tuple based on most occurrences

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

There is a *tuple*, build from two arrays, dtype = int64 .
Please bear with me for the following description.
The tuple shows the positions of black pixels from a nearly straight horizontal line in an image.

The first array is for the y coordinates and is something like
 `y_coord = np.array([268, 269, 270, 270, 270, 270, 271], dtype=np.int64)`

The second array defindes the x coordinates is like this
 `x_coord = np.array([560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566], dtype=np.int64)`

Tuple definition:
`test_tup = (y_coord, x_coord)`

I'm aiming to:

- find the value with most occurrences in the first array - that I can achieve by using:
  `max_y = np.bincount(y_coord).argmax()`
- now I would like to get the *minimum and maximum* values for the *corresponding item in the second array* and store them in variables
- the expected result would be:
  `start_x = (562, max_y) and stop_x = (565, max_y)`
  `# where 562 and 565 are the min and max values I am looking for`
- after that I will use start_x and stop_x to draw a line between those points

I tried all sorts of methods for sorting tuples, converting them to lists or to arrays and I still couldn't find one that fits the needs.
This error is usually brought up
 *ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*

Your help would be very welcome in finding the solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As for using tuples, I went with a different data structure.  I'd use the `argmax` function along axis `0`.  What my code currently does is finds the maximum and minimum `y` value then returns a numpy array of containing `y` and `x`.  I used `np.dstack` to combine the arrays before finding the min and max value.

```
import numpy as np

x_coord = np.array([560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566], dtype=np.int64)
y_coord = np.array([268, 269, 270, 270, 270, 270, 271], dtype=np.int64)

d = np.dstack((x_coord,y_coord))[0]
start_x = d[d.argmax(axis=0)[1]]
stop_x = d[d.argmin(axis=0)[1]]
```

Comment: Dear Neil, thank you for your time answering this question.  The approach you shared is indeed finding the min  & max and it converts the tuple to an `int64` to manipulate it.  Let me restate the problem: **Firstly** I am trying to find the **maximum occurence** in the **y_coord** set (in this case, the value **270**).   Based on that, I would like to find the **corresponding** minimum & maximum in the subset **x_coord** and store them into two variables.  In this case the `start_x = (562, 270)` and `stop_x = (565, 270)`   Using what you provided, I only get the basic min&max :[